# Select child elements in mongodb collection when parent has different names in each record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have below json format for my mongodb collection where i need to select child element to perform calculations but parent has **different names in every record**.

> **distribution** is the parent element and *5d39e82f9ab1* and *5d09f133* are the variable child elements in each record.

```
{"distribution" : {
        "5d39e82f9ab1" : {
            "id" : "5cfa18a", 
            "name" : "Test1", 
            "feeTarget" : "5d39e82", 
            "onBoardAgent" : {
                "debit" : 0, 
                "credit" : 0
            }, 
            "transAgent" : {
                "debit" : 0, 
                "credit" : 0
            }, 
            "redeemAgent" : {
                "debit" : 0, 
                "credit" : 0
            }, 
            "merchant" : {
                "debit" : 0, 
                "credit" : 0
            }, 
            "system" : {
                "debit" : 0, 
                "credit" : 0
            }, 
            "aggregator" : {
                "debit" : 0, 
                "credit" : 0
            }, 
            "distributor" : {
                "debit" : 0, 
                "credit" : 0
            }
        }
    }
}


{"distribution" : {
        "5d09f133" : {
            "id" : "5d09f133", 
            "name" : "test2", 
            "feeTarget" : "5d09f133", 
            "onBoardAgent" : {
                "debit" : 0, 
                "credit" : 0
            }, 
            "transAgent" : {
                "debit" : 0, 
                "credit" : 28
            }, 
            "redeemAgent" : {
                "debit" : 0, 
                "credit" : 0
            }, 
            "merchant" : {
                "debit" : 0, 
                "credit" : 0
            }, 
            "system" : {
                "debit" : 0, 
                "credit" : 7
            }, 
            "aggregator" : {
                "debit" : 0, 
                "credit" : 0
            }, 
            "distributor" : {
                "debit" : 0, 
                "credit" : 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to select and perform operations like:

Below is the probable query:

```
"$project" : {
                "distribution.*.onBoardAgent" : 1,
                Difference: { $subtract: [ "$distribution.*.onBoardAgent.debit", $distribution.*.onBoardAgent.debit" ] }
            }
        },
```

Here **"*"** is the variable name in each of my collection.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `"*"` syntax in MongoDB. To traverse your BSON document dynamically you need to use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) and [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) operators. First operator returns an array of `key-value` pairs so you have to use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to transform your nested objects

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            distribution: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $map: {
                        input: { $objectToArray: "$distribution" },
                        as: "dist",
                        in: {
                            k: "$$dist.k",
                            v: {
                                onBoardAgent: "$$dist.v.onBoardAgent",
                                difference: { $subtract: [ "$$dist.v.onBoardAgent.debit", "$$dist.v.onBoardAgent.credit" ] }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ik7yUyUOobT)

Comment: If i have to map for redeemAgent,system and merchant then in $map syntax i would need to assign different variables like k and v or entire conversion for each field?

Comment: or you could run another nested $objectToArray if you want to do that dynamically

Comment: This would make the query quite large if i add multiple fields.

Comment: @RahulAnand that's true - it would be better to redesign your schema if possible, otherwise you need to deal with large queries

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`$objectToArray`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) aggregation operator to convert your dynamic fields to key value pair

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "distribution": {
      "$objectToArray": "$distribution"
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$distribution" }
])
```

Now you will do the operations by changing your * with **v**

```
{
  "$project": {
    "distribution.v.onBoardAgent": 1,
    "Difference": {
      "$subtract": [
        "$distribution.v.onBoardAgent.debit",
        "$distribution.v.onBoardAgent.debit"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Got the objectToArray part but $subtract is throwing error : "errmsg" : "cant $subtract aarray from a array"

Comment: @RahulAnand [Where](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hr0y7a5AaMs) ?

Comment: { 
            "$project" : {
                "Difference" : {
                    "$subtract" : [
                        "$distribution.v.onBoardAgent.debit", 
                        "$distribution.v.onBoardAgent.credit"
                    ]
                }
            }
        } @Ashh on this part